# WebSphere 7 - Jython Version

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

Does anyone know of a way (using the java command or wsadmin, or......) to find out the current version of jython running behind wsadmin on a WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.31 ND environment?

Answer (score 4):

It is most likely 2.1.0, but the following mini-script should tell you.

```
import sys
print (sys.version_info)
```

If it is 2.1 see:

- https://docs.python.org/release/2.1/
- http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Within `wsadmin` `sys.version` will give the version of Jython in use.